# I cannot reach my ATV3 anymore after update MBA (late 2010) to 10.9

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, appletv

Since I updated my MacBook Air to 10.9 I cannot reach my AppleTV3 anymore. I know my MBA (Late 2010) will not be supported for mirroring anymore because of the lack of sandy bridge, but before the update I was able to stream Music and Videos out of iTunes to my ATV3.

I checked, by using IP-Scanner to see that my ATV is screened in the same network (no subnet). I tried Airparrot and Beamer.app but they cannot find the ATV either. Is there a possibility to reach them anyway? I don't want to buy a new MBA just to stream my music to ATV!

Comment: Can the ATV access content stored in iTunes using Sharing or Home Sharing?  How about other Internet-based content?  I know it seems like it should be the MBA that has the problem, since you state that that changed, but the ATV could have lost some kind of network/internet connectivity too.  If the ATV is fine, try to create a new user on the MBA, login as that user, and try to connect from iTunes to the ATV.  No simple answers, but there must be a reason and a fix!

Answer (score 1):

Have you made sure that your Apple TV (ATV) has the latest firmware?

Do you have another Mac you can try to connect to the ATV?

If you have another Mac then you could also try running [AirServer](http://www.airserver.com/) (they offer a 7 day free trial) on it and see if the Air can AirPlay to it.

You need a little more information about exactly what is going on before you can really find a solution.